# How to make the character move a certain distance when a button is pressed or tapped

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

So I'm working on a 2D game right now just to learn different stuff or codes related to making 2D games.
So I've come to a trouble where I got curious on how to make a character move a certain distance like per say 1 block per tap of button. I will give an example here. So take imagine the grid as a land.

Move a certain distance. [image: The result I want]

This one is the one my character is doing with my current code [image: The result that I don't want]
and here's my movement code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class keycontrol : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float moveSpeed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private Vector2 change;
    private Animator animator;
    bool isXMoving;
    bool isYMoving;


    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        change.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        change.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        
    if (Mathf.Abs(change.x) > Mathf.Abs(change.y))
    {
        change.y = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        change.x = 0;
    }

        animator.SetFloat("walk_right", change.x);
        animator.SetFloat("walk_left", -change.x);
        animator.SetFloat("walk_down", -change.y);
        animator.SetFloat("walk_up", change.y);

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb2d.MovePosition(rb2d.position + change * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        if(Input.GetKey("left shift"))
        {
            moveSpeed = 150;
            animator.speed = 1.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            moveSpeed = 70;
            animator.speed = 1f;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is just your movement speed. You multiply your speed with `Time.fixedDeltaTime` but that isn't necessary because that value will be constant. Instead, try just setting the speed to 1 and remove the `Time.fixedDeltaTime`.

Note: `Time.deltaTime` is used to make the character move a certain amount per frame because the shorter the time between frames, the less the character will move. `Time.fixedDeltaTime` stays constant because it is the time between each physics frame.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, the reason it keeps moving is because the input stays greater than zero. You could add a variable to check if the keys are already down to stop the movement.

There are two options here I think,

1. Make the user click everytime then want to move (press key, lift finger, press key, etc)
2. Add a timer to make it move every Nth second

---

**For (1) we could just add an variable to say we are moving already.**

```
//Changes IsXMoving and IsYMoving to a single boolean
bool isMoving = false;

///Start, Update, etc

void FixedUpdate()
{
    //Check if we are already moving - if we are not, update movement
    if (!isMoving)
    {
        rb2d.MovePosition(rb2d.position + change * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        if(Input.GetKey("left shift"))
        {
            moveSpeed = 150;
            animator.speed = 1.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            moveSpeed = 70;
            animator.speed = 1f;
        }
    }
    
    //Check we are moving by getting the magnitude - if it zero, we are still
    isMoving = (change.magnitude != 0);
}
```

**The second option (2) would basically replace this with a basic timer.**

```
//Removed IsXMoving and IsYMoving
//lastMove will store the time we last allowed movement and delay is 
//the minimum time between movements in seconds
float lastMove;
float delay = 1; //1 second



void FixedUpdate()
{
    //Check if enough time has passed to be allowed to move
    if (lastMove + delay < Time.time)
    {
        rb2d.MovePosition(rb2d.position + change * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        if(Input.GetKey("left shift"))
        {
            moveSpeed = 150;
            animator.speed = 1.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            moveSpeed = 70;
            animator.speed = 1f;
        }
        
        //Only update the time if we are moving
        if (change.magnitude > 0)
            lastMove = Time.time;
    }
}
```